# How to get a list of files in a directory with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dir

Here's what I have so far:

```
class FileRenamer
    def RenameFiles(folder_path)
        baseDirectory = folder_path

        files = Dir.glob("*")
    end
end

puts "Renaming files..."

renamer = FileRenamer.new()
files = renamer.RenameFiles("/home/papuccino1/Desktop/Test")
puts files

puts "Renaming complete."
```

The problem is that it seems to be getting files on the directory where my .rb file is running from.

How can I set the directory to where I want it to be? Notice I have the baseDirectory variable there.

Answer (score 10):

```
files = Dir.glob(File.join(folder_path, "*"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
files = Dir.glob(folder_path + '/*')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
Dir.chdir(baseDirectory)
files = Dir.glob("*")
...
```

Btw, using CamelCase for variables and methods in ruby is not good (it's only for modules and classes). Use snake_case for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want files

```
class FileRenamer
    def RenameFiles(folder_path)
        files = Dir.glob( File.join(".","*")).select{|x| test(?f,x)}
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Find.find(@path) do |path|
      if FileTest.directory?(path)
        @dirs.push(path)
      else
        @files.push(path)
      end
    end
```